# How to get RedisGraph DB backup in .rdb file along with .aof file

Tags: redis, redisgraph

I am using Redis Enterprise trail version 5.0.6. I have created RedisGraph database and persistence as "Append Only File (AOF) - fsync every 1 sec". Storing .aof file in disk properly. But I want backup file .rdg along with this .aof file.

I tried by using Save/Bgsave commands but I am getting below errors.

```
(error) command 'SAVE' is not allowed
```

Can some one help me, how to get backup in .rdb file along with .aof file.

Comment: which redisgraph version are you using?

Comment: RedisGraph version 2.0.10

Comment: Did you try BGSAVE?

Comment: Yes, for BGSAVE also showing same error

(error) command 'BGSAVE' is not allowed

Comment: Did you try 2.0.13?

Comment: No, I did not try.